# 2 DIV Container with the same height

Tags: css, html, height

I want to get the same height on two different `div` which are together in one parent `div`.
Let me show you the simple code before I explain it detailed:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box_one">
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="box_two">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width:1170px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:left;
}
#box_one{
  width:860px;
  background-color:#FCFCFC;
}
#box_two {
  float:left;
  width:310px;
  background-color:#FCFCFC;
}
```

so thats how the code look in basic. Now let me get to the problem. The first `div#box_one` will have dynamic content - I can't say how much it will be - same for `#box_two`. But I still want boths `div` to share the same height. `min-height` is here not a useful solution and setting the wrapper+body+html to `height: 100%` and both of those `dov` too isn't even worth an idea since it will crash the other layout.

So is there any way or do I have to find another way instead of using two `div`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/upeXACAq/1/edit)

All you really need is `display: table-cell`.

```
.foo {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 49%; /* not exact, just for this example */
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Some stuff in here.</div>
<div class="foo">Other stuff in here.</div>
```

Comment: Was a bit confused that it didn't work for a short time - then realized you have to remove the float:left under any circumstances

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use just a few lines of jQuery code for that, result is the best

```
    $('.parent-div').each(function(){  
        var highestBox = 0;
        $('.child-div', this).each(function(){

            if($(this).height() > highestBox) 
                 highestBox = $(this).height(); 
            });  

            $('.child-div',this).height(highestBox);
    });
```

Comment: Why should it be better to use jQuery code, instead of simple adjust the CSS a bit ?

Comment: Display:table-cell arises the positon problem.  Table cell elements just won't take the position values.